# How to visualize segment-anything mask results in a single color?

Tags: python, computer-vision, image-segmentation

I'm trying to visualize the results of image segmentation which was done by 'segment-anything'. When I do this the segmented boxes/masks are plotted with different colors. [image: as shown here] How can I plot all the masks with the same color (black) ?

```
import cv2
import supervision as sv
import numpy as np

sam_result = np.load('sam_result_multy1.npy', allow_pickle=True)
print(sam_result[0].keys())

IMAGE_PATH = 'img_mult_sk.png'
image_bgr =  cv2.imread(IMAGE_PATH)

mask_annotator = sv.MaskAnnotator()
detections = sv.Detections.from_sam(sam_result=sam_result)
annotated_image = mask_annotator.annotate(scene=image_bgr.copy(), detections=detections)


sv.plot_images_grid(
    images=[image_bgr, annotated_image],
    grid_size=(1, 2),
    titles=['source image', 'segmented image']
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can choose the mask colors when initializing the `MaskDetector`:

```py
mask_annotator = sv.MaskAnnotator(color=sv.Color.black())
```

The `color` argument can be a color or a palette. It defaults to a palette and cycles through its colors, which explains the multiple mask colors you see by default.

Comment: Hi, this created a large black square that covered the whole scene. What I want is to have the individual masks to be in black color.

Comment: You'll probably have to filter out the background mask (in red in your original example), which is preventing your other masks from being visible. For example: `detections = detections[detections.area < 0.2 * image_bgr.shape[0]*image_bgr.shape[1]]` to filter out all masks that take up over 20% of the image. Or you could filter the masks by area and remove the largest.

Comment: Hi, I have filtered this and I'm only plotting the small circular masks within. I achieve this by comparing their areas.

Comment: Is there also a way to make the mask fully transparent? I would like to retain the original colors of the image.